# npm ERR! missing script: build:universal

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run my Angular application on the server side and I am facing these errors:

> npm ERR! missing script: build:universal
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/training/.npm/_logs/2018-10-03T11_50_40_593Z-debug.log

I used the official Angular application for doing this

https://angular.io/guide/universal

The universal build is causing errors shown below:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
>   1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
>   1 verbose cli   'run',
>   1 verbose cli   'build:universal' ]
>   2 info using npm@6.2.0
>   3 info using node@v10.8.0
>   4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build:universal
>   4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
>   4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
>   4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:115:5
>   4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:418:5
>   4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:373:45)
>   4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:416:3)
>   4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:160:5)
>   4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:280:12
>   4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
>   4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
>   5 verbose cwd /home/training/Desktop/vishnu/TemplateAppv6
>   6 verbose Linux 4.4.0-134-generic
>   7 verbose argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build:universal"
>   8 verbose node v10.8.0
>   9 verbose npm  v6.2.0
>   10 error missing script: build:universal
>   11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Can you add your package.json to your question? - You may have not added the build-script in your package json..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As implied in my comment, you may have forgotten to add the build-script to your project:

From the [universal docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

> Build and run with universal: Now that you've created the TypeScript
>   and Webpack config files and configured the Angular CLI, you can build
>   and run the Universal application.
>
> First add the build and serve commands to the scripts section of the
>   package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run angular.io-example:server",
     "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
    ...
}
```

So check you package.json and try the build again..

Comment: @V5NXT : Glad I could help ;)

Comment: I kept this at end of script tag but it's not working, so between which lines we need to put this inside script tag.